# How to delete from the last node in a linked list to a specific node in that list using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

So i am trying to delete from a specific node in a linked list but the problem doesn't come from deleting from the node to end ,it comes from trying to delete from the last node to a specific node while trying to use a recursion.

This is what I currently have (deleting from the node to last node)

```
void rLL<T> :: recursiveDelete(item<T> * node)
{
if (node != nullptr)
    {
        item<T> * nodeptr = node -> next;
        delete node;
        
        size--;
        recursiveDelete(nodeptr);
        
    }
}
```

Now I have to try and switch it around.And I have no idea how to do that.
This is for a school project so please ,if possible, try to keep it simple.

edit:Let's say the list consist of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and node 5 was put in to the parameter node then 7 ,6 ,5 should be deleted in that specific order (to clear things up a bit)

Comment: Possibly as simple as doing the recursive call _first_, then do the `delete`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is to simply perform the recursive call *before* calling `delete`.

However, even if you were able to delete the specified node without failure, the code you presented would still have a major flaw - it does not update the `next` field of the node *prior to* the specified node, so you would end up leaving the list in an invalid state, as that *prior* node would become the new tail node but have a non-null `next` pointer that does not terminate the list properly.

For a single-linked list, you would have to iterate from the front of the list in order to discover that *prior* node to update.  But once you reach the specified node, and know its *previous* node, then you can use a recursive algorithm for the rest of the list, eg:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void rLL<T>::recursiveDelete(item<T> *node, item<T> *previous)
{
    if (!node) return;

    recursiveDelete(node->next, node);

    if (previous) previous->next = nullptr;

    --size;
    delete node;
}

void rLL<T>::deleteToEnd(item<T> *startNode)
{
    if (!startNode) return;

    item<T> *node = head;
    item<T> *previous = nullptr;

    while (node)
    {
        if (node == startNode)
        {
            recursiveDelete(node, previous);
            return;
        }

        previous = node;
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/9E07DP)

That being said, a double-linked list is better suited for this task, as you don't need to iterate from the front of the list at all, you can start right at the specified node, eg:

```cpp
void rLL<T>::deleteToEnd(item<T> *startNode)
{
    if (!startNode) return;

    deleteToEnd(startNode->next);

    item<T> *previous = startNode->previous;
    if (previous) previous->next = nullptr;
    if (head == startNode) head = nullptr;
    tail = previous;

    --size;
    delete startNode;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/1SRrgE)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to delete a node that points to your specific node. If I were doing this I would have 2 nodes, currentNode and prevNode. When you iterate forward you move both of them and that way when currentNode meets the specifications, you can delete prevNode. If I don't understand the question right let me know.

Comment: I want to delete from the last node in the list backwards to the parameter node so lets say 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 is in the list and 5 was the parameter node then 7 , 6 ,5 should be deleted in that order